# When is an Iterator supposed to throw exception after source modification?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

In the following snippet, an Iterator for an ArrayList is created and after that the ArrayList structurally changes. Then the Iterator is used.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(2);
list.add(1);

Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
list.clear();
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(itr.next());
}
```

As expected a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown at `itr.next()`.

Now, take a look at this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(2);
list.add(1);
int modCount = 1;

Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
do {
    list.clear();
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    modCount += 3;
} while (modCount != 1);

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(itr.next());
}
```

After a few seconds, the execution finishes without any exception, with the results being:

```
2
3
```

The ArrayList structurally changes, and its final state is the same as the first snippet, but still no exception is thrown, even though in the first snippet it did.

After taking a look in the ArrayList source code, this is expected, as the underlying modCount is of type int. Making just enought modifications to the ArrayList results in overflow of modCount, which at some point returns back to 1. The Iterator thinks that the ArrayList is unchanged, and no exception is thrown.

In Java SE 12 docs, for the ArrayList class it is stated:

> *Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification.*

It's clear that the Iterators can make "mistakes", but again that's for unsynchronized concurrent modification, right? But, second snippet above is synchronized.

What is happening here? Is the Iterator in the second snippet supposed to behave like that? And if so, then wouldn't a modCount of type long be a little better (still the problem won't go away, but 2^64 + 1 modifications are not feasible to be performed in reasonable amounts of time).

This can be observed in other `Collection`s too, that use the same int modCount mechanism.

Comment: So your question is basically: why does the iterator fail to throw an exception,when I have created a synthetic case to produce a modCount that will trick the iterator into thinking nothing was changed. It is a nice trick, but a bit of a fake question. In real use cases, it is unlikely (though still possible) that this occurs.

Comment: You could also use reflection to adjust the `modCount` in the list and iterator. The code would then also not throw a `CME` but it is far away from usable/production code. You can almost always trick out classes, but you literally gain nothing

Comment: What "fake question" is even supposed to be? Of course its synthetic, that's a way to test software.

Comment: Given the modCount is a best effort modification check, and this case is unlikely to occur in real code (it is unlikely for 2^32 modifications to occur between creating an iterator and a check by the iterator in genuine code), it is a fake situation. And the way your question is phrased makes it sophistry and not a genuine question in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking it a little bit more, I came to the conclusion:

1. If an Iterator throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`, then the source was **structurally modified** while it was in an ongoing iteration.
2. If the source gets structurally modified while an Iterator of it was in an ongoing iteration, that Iterator **may** or **may not** throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

With that in mind the only reason an Iterator tries to throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` is to help in debugging. Better than nothing, especially in the average case.

Using a long instead of an int in modCount will increase the chance of *may* and decrease the chance of *may not* in 2. But only with a type that can hold infinite number of digits one can make the *may* have a chance of 1.0 and the *may not* have a chance of 0.0 (at least with that architecture of course). Therefore, no matter how many finite digits a modCount uses, it won't have an effect asymptotically.

Answer (score 2):

The next sentence from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs*.

You're just getting lucky that (or, rather, you're constructing a very precise situation in which) your code doesn't throw a CME.

I wouldn't read too much into the emphasis of the preceding sentence on "unsynchronized concurrent modification". A pedantic reading of this is that because one thing can happen, and that breaks the guarantee, the guarantee is broken overall, so it doesn't matter how else the guarantee might be broken.

Comment: I am aware about the Javadoc, what I want to know, is if the Iterator is only allowed to make mistakes on unsynchronized modification or can still allow cases like that, even in synchronized modification.

Answer (score 0):

All your doing is creating a scenario where the modCount will eventually wrap around until it will be in such as state as to reflect that no modification occurred, thus no CME.  Perhaps  you wanted the modCount to be a long instead of an int.